# Boot options doesn't contain second partition of a usb

Tags: boot, usb, partitioning, bios

I want to create two partitions on my USB memory and I also want to make the second one be bootable with an ISO file of an ubuntu image. By using `fdisk`, first I created a DOS partition table, then I created two partitions and finally write them on USB. Then I made filesystems of FAT32 for both of them using `mkfs.vfat` command. Then by using `dd` command I copied my ISO file to the second partition of USB. But, in the BIOS settings, I can't find the second partition of USB and I see that just the first partition is detected. I tried that, on another computer and that worked just fine but on my computer, it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Writing iso makes a bootable usb only if written on whole USB. options available to you - create two partition on USB and install grub on USB flash drive  ,copy the iso to second partition and manually add grub entry (different iso will have different entry, comment if you want help with that ) (use NTFS or ext4 filesystem for second partition instead of fat32 if iso greater than 4gb)     or.    have one USB partition with grub installed and iso in same partition. Also it might be worth mentioning what you ultimately trying to a achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

I will not use Multiple partitions on a USB drive, I like a tool named WinSetupFromUSB ([www.winsetupfromusb.com/downloads/](http://www.winsetupfromusb.com/downloads/)).

You can download it and then you can place multiple ISO images in a USB drive and when you will boot from USB it will show a menu for choosing bootable image. It supports both BIOS/UEFI and windows editions from 2000.

Although no Linux editions are available but you can give a try in WINE.

Comment: exactly. manually method should work too, install grub and add the iso entries

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to create a multi-boot USB with Windows editions.

You need specialized third-party software for it, since Windows itself does not
support multi-partition USB. The specialized app will still make it work.

The disk software contained in the BIOS is very limited, since it is not
supposed to do much beyond loading up software from the first partition
of the disk. The booted software will have the required drivers and the
software to better analyze and use all disks and partitions.

See the article
[5 Apps to Create Multiboot USB – Linux and Windows ISOs Supported](https://www.linuxbabe.com/apps/create-multiboot-usb-linux-windows-iso),
which reviews in detail and with screenshots the following:

- SARDU MultiBoot USB and DVD Creator
- MultiBootUSB
- MultiSystem
- YUMI
- WinSetupFromUSB

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I think that is not a problem with Windows. My problem is in BIOS settings. It doesn't detect the second partition. And I also tried that on another computer but it was detected there.

Comment: Multi-partition requires the right software. The BIOS has very limited disk software, as see my addition above.